# How to refresh a google map manually?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a marker - creating activity, when the user can customise the position. After this activity is closed I want to put the new, and the ealier saved markers on my google map. (so UPDATE the map)

I am using this function:

```
onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
```

but it is not working properly. I have to close and reopen the app to see the changes.

Comment: try             mMap.clear();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you override `onResume` in your activity/fragment, you can do work once the marker creation activity closes. In there, you can update your map like you would in `onMapReady` if you set your `GoogleMap` object as global. For example:

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

...

...onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    ...

}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if(mGoogleMap != null){ //prevent crashing if the map doesn't exist yet (eg. on starting activity)
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        // add markers from database to the map
    }
}
```

You could consider making your marker adding into a function that gets called in `onResume` and `onMapReady` to make your code more maintainable.

Comment: How do i get the `(GoogleMap googleMap)` in the function onResume, to make mGoogleMap equal googleMap?

Comment: @mosómaci In the `onMapReady` function I added an assignment of `mGoogleMap` to `googleMap` so that the map object is used when the `onResume` code runs.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.